# Why is there an Error when using the format.join function

Tags: python, sql

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Filterdata({})".format(' ,'.join(df.columns)))
```

What could be the error in this Code please.

i keep getting this

> OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Does `Filterdata(` need a closing parenthesis?

Comment: i have closed it. the error is still there.

Comment: Perhaps you should print out the `"CREATE TABLE ..."` formatted string before passing it to `execute()`. You might be able to see the problem.

Comment: thank you. i think i discovered the error. the code was unable to read my first rows which contains strings not integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try ending inverted commas before the last parenthesis.

Like this

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Filterdata({}).format(' ,'.join(df.columns))")

Comment: Thanks boss but it failed.  OperationalError: unrecognized token: "{"  that was the error it produced.